# cannot locate file in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My goal is to

1. Get postman scripts through an API call in the build stage
2. Run these scripts in the test stage

I have step 1 working, but I cannot seem to find the files that I pull from the API call.
This is the log of the API call to get the postman scripts:

```
2020-02-11T13:54:34.8779080Z attempting to call Postman API for environment..
2020-02-11T13:54:34.8781038Z file /home/vsts/work/1/a/postman\EA.API.pipeline.json Saved!
```

This is the result of the run postman script step in the test stage (I try to access both pilot.environment and EA.API.pipeline.json):

```
error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/a/postman/environments/pilot.environment.json'
```

Now an option I have considered is that these directories get wiped between stages. I get the scripts in the build stage, and try to run them in the test stage. This is why after pulling the scripts, I make sure that they are actually in the storage, and afterwards I try to publish them as an artifact:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.sh
/home/vsts/work/1/a
├── postman\
├── postman\EA.API.pipeline.json
```

But in the next step in the same build stage, I try to publish these tests as an artifact, and I get this error:

```
##[error]Path does not exist: /home/vsts/work/1/a/postman/EA.API.pipeline.json
```

This is the yaml:

```
     - task: OneLuckiDev.getPostmanJSON.vsts-release-web-test.oneLuckiGetPostmanScripts@1
        displayName: 'Get Postman Script'
        inputs:
          fileLocation: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/postman'
          apiKey: '$(PostmanAPIKey)'
      - script: 'sudo apt-get install tree'
        displayName: 'install tree'
      - script: 'tree "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
        displayName: 'run tree'            
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: postman API tests'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/postman/EA.API.pipeline.json'
          artifact: PostmanAPITests
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Why can't I find my files?

Comment: If you publish the whole $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) what du you see in your artifact?

Comment: I agree with gungthar's answer. It is caused by you are using Linux agent, and you can also see from the log, that the path of `EA.API.pipeline.json` file is `/home/vsts/work/1/a/postman\EA.API.pipeline.json`. So, in your Publish task, you should change your `targetpath` value as `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/postman\EA.API.pipeline.json`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your slashes. Your task OneLuckiDev.getPostmanJSON.vsts-release-web-test.oneLuckiGetPostmanScripts@1 seems to have been written for a Windows agent, but you are using a Linux agent. This is causing it to append a backslash when saving your scripts which to your agent is just seen as part of the filename. The file postman\EA.API.pipeline.json is your saved script.

Comment: This solution worked for me , in .net 6.0, c#, the slash were back slash before, and this code is in test , locally I was able to read the file and use the data however when using yaml file in azure devops I configured build and tried to execute tests, it was throwing file not found because in pipeline yaml file, I was configured  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'...

After correctly updating, code is as below:

 using (var stream = new FileStream("Resources//Data_With_Only_SourceGateInDate.xlsm", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))