# AzurePowerShell task cannot find filePath

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script in Azure Yaml Pipelines and I'm getting this error:

```
##[error]The term 'D:\a\1\s\myPowershellFile.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

**Code:**

```
jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(myEnvironment)
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:          
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            displayName: 'Run Powershell script'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureConnectionName)
              scriptType: filePath
              scriptPath: './myPowershellFile.ps1'
              azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
```

The file is pushed out to the repo for the branch that is triggering the build. I've also tried referencing the path explicitly with `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. Version 4 also does not work. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops#samples) this should be working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research I discovered [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) which says that files are not automatically downloaded for deployment jobs. I added this step, and that fixed the issue!

`- checkout: self`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help noticing but you have used the **forward slash "/"** as the seperator for the filepath instead of a **back-slash "\"** like in the example you are pointing to in the azure docs :

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: my-arm-service-connection
    scriptType: filePath
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myscript.ps1
```

This looks like the reason why.

There is a similar issue here. looks like it depends on whether you are using a windows or linux agent : [cannot locate file in azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170787/cannot-locate-file-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

Comment: forward-slashes generally _do_ work even on windows agents; but the leading dot may be what's causing the problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried both with forward and back slashes, with and without a leading dot. I am using a Windows agent, not Linux as was the issue with the other post.